# Recursion of Palindrome without using auxiliary function?

Tags: c#, .net, recursion

I've written a recursion that checks if a string is a palindrome :

```
public static bool IsPalindrome(string value)
{
    if ( value == null )
        return false;

    if ( value.Length == 0 )
        return true;

    return isPalindrome(value, 0, value.Length - 1);
}

private static bool isPalindrome(string value, int startChar, int endChar)
{
    if ( value[startChar] != value[endChar] )
        return false;

    if ( startChar >= endChar )
        return true;

    return isPalindrome(value, startChar + 1, endChar - 1);
}
```

However I tried to find a way to do the same algorithm without using an auxiliary method that does the recursion (`isPalindrome(.. , .. , ..)`) however I still need the call of `isPalindrome(...)`  .

How can I combine the two functions into one , where the recursion algorithm wouldn't make a call to any additional functions ?

Comment: Why changing what is clear, small-enough and quick?

Comment: @varocarbas - If the only purpose of the method `isPalindrome` is to support the processing of `IsPalindrome` then I think the point is **encapsulation** - one of the four main tenets of OOP.

Comment: @Enigmativity You are basically saying that it is necessary to blindly apply an overall-valid truth regardless of the specific situation because you have to obey a set of commandments proposed by an always-right abstract set of ideas (the ones you call OOP)? And what will happen if I prefer to take the commandments as rough generic recommendations and mostly focused on my (and others’) actual practical expertise to deliver the best solution in each situation? Would I go to the OOP's hell? LOL.

Comment: @Enigmativity ... I am kidding, but hopefully that you get the underlying idea; that is: I don’t think that programming is about blindly executing abstract ideas.

Comment: @varocarbas - I can only respond with, "Yes, Minister." That rant was awesome! ;-)

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would replacing the separate method with an anonymous one be acceptable:

```
public static bool IsPalindrome(string value)
{
    if (value == null)
        return false;

    if (value.Length == 0)
        return true;

    Func<string, int, int, bool> ip = null;
    ip = (v, sc, ec) =>
    {
        if (v[sc] != v[ec])
            return false;

        if (sc >= ec)
            return true;

        return ip(v, sc + 1, ec - 1);
    };

    return ip(value, 0, value.Length - 1);
}
```

Comment: @ron just to clarify... It's the same solutions as your's just a lot less readable...  what you wrote originally is better... though I like this one for cleverness :-)

Comment: @AK_: Totally agree with you , I like the use of anonymous functions  , and recursively ? brilliant ! +1 .

Comment: @AK_ - I wouldn't say a **lot** less readable. But, what it loses in readability it makes up for in encapsulation and maintainability (of itself and its class).

Comment: Less readable = less maintainable... it doesn't affect encapsulation at all, because the second method is **private** ... It's a matter of style more than anything...

Comment: @AK_ - The second method is only `private` to methods outside of the class. Inside the class is is perfectly visible unless it is encapsulated via an anonymous method.

Comment: @AK_ - I looked at class maintainability, not the specific method, so it's also more maintainable because the anonymous method is contained within the method that needs it. It always ensures that it is close. They never become methods that are defined in different places within the class. It's also more maintainable because you can reduce the total number of methods within the class.

Comment: I guess that including a reference to performance aspects here is recommendable (mainly after the long discussion in AK_'s answer). As you can see there, I built a simplistic testing framework (which AK_ didn't like too much and preferred to modify a bit). I included your code and the conclusion is that, for small enough inputs (<100 characters and < 50 iterations), your approach is the slowest one (well... the slowest one by far is the AK_'s second attempt, but did already said that this was a mistake) although not by too much...

Comment: ... for big enough input conditions (= what I call completely unrealistic but that, according to AK_, should be brought into picture while analysing the performance), AK_'s approach keeps getting worse and worse with respect to the original method and also to yours, which seems to follow an evolution equivalent to the original method (i.e., not notably slower, like in the case of AK_'s first approach). In any case, it is never faster than the original method (and I tried quite a few unrealistic enough input configurations)...

Comment: Summary: for what I call common situations (i.e., over 90% of the cases where this method might be used?!), AK_'s first method is the fastest one, although not much faster than the second one (original, perfect in my opinion, approach) and, yours the slowest one (+ a bit less clear, in my opinion too). For what I call unrealistic conditions (i.e., strings consisting in thousands of characters and calling these functions over and over thousands of times in a row), the behaviour of your approach is certainly better than AK_'s one, but worse than the original recursive approach...

Comment: ... I don't know what your OOP god (;)) thinks about this, but I am still not so sure that making an effort to change a perfectly working approach which additionally is the overall-fastest/best-performing alternative (at least, as per your answers) and whose algorithm is the clearest one (in my opinion, at least) is a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

Here:

```
public static bool IsPalindrome(string value)
{
    if ( value == null )
        return false;

    if ( value.Length <= 1 )
        return true;

    if ( value[0] != value[value.Length - 1] )
        return false;

    return IsPalindrome(value.Substring(1,value.Length - 2));
}
```

Performance would suck though... because this allocates n/2 strings...
You could do something a little smarter with an array window wrapper... But i don't recall .Net having those built in...

---

Option 2 :

```
public static bool IsPalindrome(IEnumerable<char> value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return false;

        if (value.Count() <= 1)
            return true;

        if (value.First() != value.Last())
            return false;

        return IsPalindrome(value.Skip(1).Take(value.Count() - 1));
    }
```

This has some hope of better performance... depending on how LINQ does specializations...

**Tested the second one, and its dreadfully slow....**

Comment: Performance would suck? Recursive functions are extremely quick. The original version of the OP was certainly very quick and your version shouldn't change things appreciably. A lower number of lines or an in-built method doesn't mean quicker (in quite a few cases, it means right the contrary).

Comment: I got your point. I meant that mentioning bad performance in a so quick algorithm is not too accurate. You can do some tests by your own; I don't think that your modification (or any other one proposed here) will provoke a noticeable difference in speed. But there will certainly be relevant differences with respect to other methodologies.

Comment: @varocarbas you should check what you're saying with a profiler (one that also shows memory)...

Comment: I don't need to do that because I have created tons of algorithms with strings and I know the impact on final (at the macro level; what you can actually measure while comparing different algorithms) performance of something like `Substring` (= none). Bear in mind that not using this approach would imply to use a different one with different drawbacks. In any case, you are free to do some tests to support your time/memory claims (include them in your answer and prove me wrong).

Comment: here, tested it with a string of 5000 characters... the OP's solution takes 0.0006671 seconds. Mine takes 0.1759083 s .  Substring allocates a new string and copys, which in practice can take a LOT of time.... Now please go do your homework.

Comment: This has been funny; because I was also working on this. Unlikely you (who seem to like generally talking and referring to abstract statements with no proof), I have created a code to help understand the point: http://pastebin.com/i3tgMTBb

Comment: As you can confirm (you have just execute this code), with this input your approach (the first one you wrote) is even quicker than the original version of the OP, the second quickest (not far away) is the original version of the OP and the last one (by far) is your second version which you claim to be better. Note that I have also increase the length of the input (to over 100 characters) and the times remain equivalent. Also note that the difference between your original approach (by far your quickest contribution here) and the original OP's approach is very small; it seems...

Comment: ... that your approach is better, but the different is so small that just by changing the order of the elements, the results vary slightly. In any case, it does seem that your approach is definetively better.

Comment: My test is worse? With a loop or a multiple-trial approach, your measurements are not reliable at all. What real-life problem involves 5000 characters?!

Comment: Sorry I cannot test the 5000 character option because the slowest approach (your second one) takes ages just with the first iteration :)

Comment: Although I do recognise the notable effect of `Substring` for the 5000 character example; but as said I wasn't expecting so tremendously big inputs and, in any case, I would have always preferred the original recursive approach.

Comment: obviously on very small inputs my version will be faster. but the moment you allocate enough strings create memory pressure, or invoke the GC, my solution is **orders of magnitude** slower...

Comment: Firstly, you are tricking the underlying idea; certainly you are using 100 characters but also 1 million iterations (again something completely outside the most logical conditions). Secondly, you should also include the results for your second approach :)

Comment: Sorry but to make your first approach orders of magnitude slower than the original OP's one you have to test really hard input conditions (or crazily big strings or lots of iterations). But your second approach is orders of magnitude slower even under simplistic conditions.

Comment: OK. Then I am happy to recognise that, under extreme conditions, `Substring` does have some effect on performance. And this confirms my original idea: if you have a good enough recursive approach, why changing it at all?!

Answer (score 1):

How about using a `while`-loop:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(IsPalindrome("TEST"));
        Console.WriteLine(IsPalindrome("TESTSET"));
    }

    public static bool IsPalindrome(string value)
    {
        if ( value == null )
            return false;

        if ( value.Length == 0 )
            return true;

        int startChar = 0;
        int endChar = value.Length - 1;

        while(value[startChar] == value[endChar] && startChar < endChar)
        {
            startChar++;
            endChar--;
            if(startChar >= endChar) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
False
True
```

I like your recursive solution much more though.

**EDIT**

Or... you could do it with one statement:

```
public static bool IsPalindrome(string value)
{
    if ( value == null )
        return false;

     return value == new String(value.ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray());
}
```

**EDIT**

And another solution using a `for`-loop. It is similar to doing a reverse and then compare.

```
public static bool IsPalindrome(string value)
{
    if ( value == null )
        return false;

    for(int i = 0, j = value.Length - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        if(value[i] != value[j]) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Your other solution (in the bottom , `Reverse()`) uses the algorithm that I'm trying to implement ...

Comment: Three solutions and none of them fulfill "How can I combine the two function into one, where the recursion algorithm wouldn't make a call to any additional functions?" As they are no longer recursive.

Comment: Oh, ah! I understand what the OP means now... I'm feeling a little embarrassed.

Comment: I didn't downvote my friend ! I'm after a solution that keeps my algorithm , I don't want to replace the recursion with a while/for loop , just combine it into one function with the same logic .

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this:

```
public static bool IsPalindrome(string value)
{
    if ( value == null )
        return false;

    if ( value.Length == 0 )
        return true;

    int i=0;
    bool _cont = true;
    while(_cont){

        if ( value[startChar+i] != value[endChar-i] ){
            _cont = false;
            return false;


        if ( (startChar+i) >= (endChar-i) ){
            i++;
        }
        else{
            _cont = false;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The variable `_cont` is of no use. It is set to false and then the method exits.

Comment: I'm sorry I stepped on your toes. I down voted and I gave a reason for it. That's how stackoverflow works, isn't it? And yes, I edited my answer a few times and I got the OP's question wrong, but there's nothing wrong with that is it?